# How to pass the new line on ADB

Tags: android, shell, adb

I would like to be able to send a SMS from my Android phone while it's connected to my computer using the following ADB commands so i refered this link.
      [send a SMS from my Android phone](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCQQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F17580199%2Fsending-a-sms-on-android-through-adb&ei=aAUQVaDILsGiugTwroHYBQ&usg=AFQjCNFmoYE2BXAvREHwJab2G7hiikisRw&bvm=bv.88528373,d.c2E&cad=rja)

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.SENDTO -d sms:CCXXXXXXXXXX --es sms_body "SMS BODY \n GOES HERE" --ez exit_on_sent true
adb shell input keyevent 22
```

`adb shell input keyevent 66`

Its working fine for me so when I started testing it, I can send characters,white spaces,special characters but not the new line. Say like I had 2 lines of text when I tried to pass, first line characters were sent but not the second line ones. So I want to know how to send the many lines through adb. Even I tried all escape sequence characters but still I couldn't pass. So anyone can tell me how to solve this ..  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is reported to work:

```
adb shell "NL=$'\n' ; am start -a android.intent.action.SENDTO -d sms:CCXXXXXXXXXX --es sms_body \"SMS BODY ${NL} GOES HERE\" --ez exit_on_sent true"
```

Comment: Great!  Updating answer to only show the one that worked, for future readers.